# Cap decimals globally

Tags: php

I am looking for an option to **globally** set or handle PHPs float numbers to (up to) 4 decimals. I also need to store those values, so it is not (primarily / only) about displaying them.

**Examples**:

```
input => expected output(s)
1 => 1.0000 or 1
1.001 => 1.001 or 1.0010
1.00001 => 1.0000 or 1
123456.0 => 123456.0 or 123456.0000 or 123456
```

I am not looking for [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), unless it can be applied globally. number_format needs to be applied manually each and every time afaik.
Also, I am not looking for `ini_set("precision", 4)`, because it will not only cap the decimals but the whole number, e.g.:

```
ini_set("precision", 4);
123456.0 => 1.235E+5
```

My cheapest approach right now is to get and format all numbers from the output string, but then again I would have to store these manually instead of accessing them directly through the PHP script when they are called, so this is not a good solution.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Without knowing why exactly you're doing this, you will probably want to create your own class that contains the whole number part and the fractional part, separately, then combines them when needed. Something like [working with money](http://culttt.com/2014/06/04/working-money-currency-php/)

Comment: It's not a XY Problem @user176717. Stated above that I need to format all float numbers (there are a lot), which is what number_format does. Building a class for that would be much more of an overhead than applying number_format everytime. I'm searching for a way to avoid this kind of overhead.